# position of div and li with z-index - a dropdown menu - once more

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, z-index, opencart

I have a dropdown menu build like - these are links showed in 3 rows:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and if there is a sibbling menu (dropdown) another `<div>` is placed in parent `<li>`. Everything is made with php from a database as a part of OpenCart template:

```
<div id="menu" class="third_color_bg grid_12">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a class="sixth_color_bg" href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
      <div class="sixth_color_border">
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
        <ul>
          <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
          <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
          <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
          <li><a class="secondary_color" href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo  $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>

     <div class="categories_spacer"></div>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is, that the dropdown from a link in the first row appears under a link from the second row as such:

http://www.3aracing.com.au/test/image/menu.jpg

This is the css:

```
/* menu */
#menu {
   /*height: 46px;*/
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   -khtml-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #DDDDDD;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #DDDDDD;
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #DDDDDD;
}
#menu ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
#menu > ul > li {
    background: url("../image/tabs-border-image.png") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;    /* default: 20 !!! */
    }

#menu > ul > li:hover {

}
#menu > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 8px 12px 8px 12px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 6; /* default: 6 !!! */
}
#menu > ul > li > div {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute; /* !!! */
    z-index: 9999; /* !!! */
    border:3px solid;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
}
#menu > ul > li:hover > div {

}
#menu > ul > li > div > ul {
   padding-left:15px;
   list-style: disc outside url("../image/list1.png");
   display: table-cell;
}
#menu > ul > li ul + ul {
   padding-left: 20px;
}
#menu > ul > li ul > li > a {
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 4px;
   display: block;
   white-space: nowrap;
   min-width: 120px;

}
#menu > ul > li ul > li > a:hover {
color:white;
}
#menu > ul > li > div > ul > li > a {

}

/*#menu > ul > li:first-child {
     margin-left: 4px;

}
I don't need it
*/
```

I tried to work with `z-index`, `position` and so on, but it didn't change a thing... Is it possible to make a parent `div` appear below a sibbling `div`? Maybe that is the problem? Dropdown should be over the Level 1 links...

http://jsfiddle.net/bo2nz7y8/1/
Sorry for some crap in it - take it from the whole code.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Could you make a fiddle please???

Comment: There it is: http://jsfiddle.net/bo2nz7y8/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you need, but I commented the `position: relative` from `#menu ul li` .

http://jsfiddle.net/bo2nz7y8/2/

Comment: That did the trick, now I have to think how and why I didn't find it myself. Thank you!